# jQuery, on click, toggle field like it is toggling class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<table id="myTable" style="width: 650px;">
    <thead>
    <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Supplier</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
<td>Fish</td>
<td>299</td>
<td>BlueHouse</td>
<td>
<form action="method">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1" />
<input class="hideme" type="text" name="amount" value"" />
</td>
<td>
<input class="hidden" type="button" name="Add" />
</form>
</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable > tbody tr').live('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
background: #CCC;
}
.hideme{
display: none;
}
```

Which works like when you click on one of the 's thats inside , then it will highlight it by toggling the CSS class "highlight".

Now what I would like to do also is showing the input fields that has the class "hideme".
First I thought to do $('.hideme').show(), but since there's more 's than one, this wouldnt work. And i would like it to show the input fields for the current toggled .

So when you click again on the tr to toggle 'off' (so it doesnt have the highlight class), i would like to have the input fields to hide again.

Hope you understood, otherwise just comment.

How can i do this?

Comment: You mentioned that there are more .hideme input element, where are those placed in your html? In your sample html, there is just one element with class .hideme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable > tbody tr').live('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        $(this).find('input[type=text]').toggleClass('hideme');
    });
```

*UPDATE* To avoid the toggle when you focus on the INPUT

```
$('#myTable > tbody tr').live('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.tagName == 'INPUT') return false;
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    $(this).find('.hideme').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add '`$(this).find('.hideme').toggle();` to the tr click event.

```
 $('#myTable > tbody tr').live('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    $(this).find('.hideme').toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pdbQH/1/

Comment: what can you do if to prevent the toggling when you try to focus on the input field?

Comment: @Karem http://jsfiddle.net/pdbQH/3/ see this js fiddle where your issue is addressed.